# Getting the HTML Markup from a dynamically constructed div

Tags: c#, asp.net

How can I get the markup for something I created like this

```
Div MyDiv = new Div("Test");
```

I essentially want to get a string with the contents

```
string SomeString = "<div>Test</div>";
```

Or maybe even

```
string SomeString = "<div id="MyDiv">Test</div>;
```

Is there any way I can do that?

Comment: You would need to use javascript if you want to get the final client html.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to give the div an id and a runat="server" attribute.  If\when the page is posted back to the codebehind, use the InnerHTML property.  Example:

```
<div id="myDiv" runat="server" />
```

And in your codebehind

```
string contents = myDiv.InnerHTML;
```

If you only need this data client side, use javascript, like mentioned in the comments above.  You can use the following code:

```
var x = document.getElementById('myDiv').innerHTML;
```

If you already have jQuery, then:

```
var x = $('myDiv').html();
```